# How would I toggle between states in JavaScript which have been created programmatically?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I changed the opacity via JS on these `li` elements, which are just squares in a `ul` element. Anyway, I wanted to see if I could just toggle the opacity back and forth, and can't for the life of me figure out how.

```
<ul id='grid'>
    <li class="yellow" alt="yellow"></li>
    <li class="purple" alt="purple"></li>
    <li class="blue" alt="blue"></li>
    <li class="pink" alt="pink"></li>
    <li class="green" alt="green"></li>
    <li class="ygreen" alt="ygreen"></li>
    <li class="gray" alt="gray"></li>
    <li class="red" alt="red"></li>
</ul>

var grid = document.getElementById('grid');

    function changeOpacity(e) {
        if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) {
            var clickedItem = e.target;
            clickedItem.style.opacity = '.5';
        }

        e.stopPropagation();
    }

    grid.addEventListener('click', changeOpacity, false);
```

I thought of adding another if statement inside like so would work...

```
 function changeOpacity(e) {
        if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) {
            var clickedItem = e.target;
            clickedItem.style.opacity = '.5';
        }

        e.stopPropagation();

        (clickedItem.style.opacity = '.5') ? clickedItem.style.opacity = '1';
    }
```

But all i get is:
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;`

**UPDATE**

```
function changeOpacity(e) {
        if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) {
            var clickedItem = e.target;
            clickedItem.style.opacity = '.5';
        }

        e.stopPropagation();

       (clickedItem.style.opacity === '.5') ? clickedItem.style.opacity = '1' : clickedItem.style.opacity = '.5';
    }
```

Comment: Even ignoring the syntax error in the ternary statement on the last line, your `if` statement will possibly  set the opacity to .5, but then your ternary statement will immediately set it back to 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(clickedItem.style.opacity = '.5')` should be `(clickedItem.style.opacity === '.5')`

You're using the wrong equality operator. That's not the cause of the syntax error, though.

**You're getting the syntax error because that's not a full ternary operator**. It should look like:

```
condition ? answer1 : answer2
```

Currently, you only have `answer1`.

**Maybe what you're looking for is something like this**:

```
clickedItem.style.opacity = clickedItem.style.opacity === '.5' ? '1' : '.5';
```

That's a long, drawn out ternary statement though. I might suggest just going with a plain old `if...else`. More readable.

## Edit

Try something like this (see the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cb6ttrjg/)):

```
var grid = document.getElementById('grid');

grid.addEventListener('click', changeOpacity, false);

function changeOpacity(e) {
    var el = e.target;

    if(el.classList.contains('half')) {
      el.classList.remove('half');  
    } else {
      el.classList.add('half');   
    }
}
```

CSS:

```
.half {
  opacity: .5;
}
```

Usually better to just toggle classes rather than rely on inconsistent DOMElement style objects.

I leave the semantics of the class names to you (`.half` is really terrible).

Comment: But `=` won't actually cause a syntax error, it just won't behave as the OP exects.

Comment: Thanks Josh, WOW I was `assigning` rather than checking! I tried the above. But it strangely it didn't work!

Comment: Thanks Josh, this works! Interesting. I heard that accessing the DOM like this is taxing...SO in the end it's easier to just add a class and toggle off like you have done?

Comment: @AntonioOrtiz, No problem. What do you mean it's taxing? Yes, it's usually understood to be best practice to manipulate style by the addition/removal of classes rather than setting style properties directly in your JavaScript (for many reasons, one of which is extensibility.)

Comment: I read that creating nodes dynamically using the DOM api causes performance issues. Which makes sense I suppose; Like for example ,if you made a `ul` list and then filled all those lists with textNodes AND then did something to them (looping over them etc. ) that might be a bit much...

Comment: @AntonioOrtiz, firstly, the above solution doesn't create nodes dynamically. It's simply adding/removing class names. Secondly, accessing the DOM API is the core of web development, it's bound to happen. The trick is doing it concisely and elegantly. Thirdly, you're going to rarely see performance issues by simply accessing the DOM or iterating over a list, even heavily, with most modern browsers. I suspect you may be reading outdated literature. Still, yes, it is something to consider, but I would suggest primarily focusing on readable, extensible code.

Comment: Oh I knew what your solution was doing (adding removing class names); I was talking about the way I was originally approaching the task, when I was adding the styles dynamically. I was imagining a solution where the toggle was being created dynamically too. I could have misread a section in this book https://leanpub.com/tspa_jumpstart but it mentions something about redrawing the DOM...Thanks again for your help. I checked out your blog & found your post about why people add a semi-colons before their IIFE great! Until your post, haven't found any information regarding that pattern/practice!

Comment: @AntonioOrtiz, yes re-drawing the DOM is expensive, and you want to limit it as much as possible (especially when heavily using a framework like AngularJS, for example), but in most use cases, as long as you're not doing anything ridiculous like iterating over thousands of elements or whatever, you're going to rarely see performance issues (and most of the small performance issues you see will pale in comparison to other issues, such as those related to networks, etc.)

Comment: @AntonioOrtiz, glad to hear that you found some use in one of my blog posts! Feel free to let me know if you have any questions or anything.